# Laravel Passport Route redirects to login page

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.3 & Passport.

When using Postman to test any route I have set in api.php file it always returns the login page. Here is an example of my testing route:

```
Route::get('/getKey', function() {
    return 'hello';
})->middleware('client_credentials');
```

Postman params:

```
Accept application/json
Authorization Bearer <then my key>
```

I have set middleware to 'auth:api' per another solution I found while searching for the answer.

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('auth:api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

I've tried just about every solution that has worked for others but still no luck. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

UPDATE
So I finally got something to work. I created a consumer app and created a few test functions. I was able to consume the api, with verification of token. However, hitting this Route no longer returns my login page, but instead now returns nothing. So its still not working for whatever reason.

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {

    return $request->user();
})->middleware('client_credentials');
```

Answer (score 68):

The redirection to the defined login route is occurring in the app\Exceptions\Handler.php class.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

The function tries to detect whether it is being called from an API (it which case it returns a 401 Unauthorized reponse with JSON message) and if not it will redirect to the login page according to the comments it

> Converts an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response

To resolve the issue in postman, on the request click on the Headers tab and add:

```
key:   Accept
value: application/json
```

I'm pretty new to this so am not sure whether this is a header we should be adding when testing all API calls with Postman or just a nusience with how this laravel method is setup.

Anyway this would solve your issue with being redirected to the login page, however it's a sign your underlying authentication isn't working

Comment: Note that in more recent versions of Laravel (e.g. 5.5x) the `unauthenticated` method is no longer in App\Exceptions\Handler.php but in Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php. The app's Handler.php extends the core handler, so `unauthenticated` will need to be overridden.

Comment: Geeze, spent hours looking for this,,,,

Comment: that's it. thanks

Answer (score 19):

You need to add `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN` to your every request's header. Also, for latest version Laravel 5.5 or above. You need to add `Accept: application/json` to request header too.

Comment: The main thing to notice is the accept json. This worked for me fetch("/api/customers", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(res => {
                console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
            });

Answer (score 15):

Add this code on Headers on postman.

```
key           Value
Accept        application/json
```

Answer (score 7):

It is coded to check whether the request comes from Ajax. In that case you will receive the following json if authentication fails:

```
{
"error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Otherwise it will assume you are using a browser and it will redirect to Html login page for authentication.

You can add the following header to your request to simulate an Ajax request:

```
X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

From laravel 5.8 till the current 6.0 version there is a a middleware located at the app/http/Middleware which is \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate, it has a method

> redirectTo

with the code

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

> Re-write this to

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {

        if (! ($request->expectsJson() || collect($request->route()->middleware())->contains('api'))) {
            return route('login');
        }

    }
```

**What this code does is to return a `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector` *instance* and sets it as the `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $redirectTo parameter` . which is passed to `\App\Exceptions@render` by laravel.**

At the render function you can write a logic to catch an `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` exception.

****Here is my own implementation****

```
     /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {


        /**
         * Render an Authentification exception when user trying to viditing a route or 
         * Perform an action is not properly authenticated
         */
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {


            return $this->unauthenticated($request,$exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return $exception->redirectTo()
                    ? redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo())
                    : response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in many of the answers the reason this happens is indeed the code:

```
if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
    return route('login');
}
```

in app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php

One way to solve this is to wrap your api requests in Middleware that adds 'Accept: application/json' to the header of those requests.

I got this idea from this article: https://medium.com/@martin.riedweg/laravel-5-7-api-authentification-with-laravel-passport-92b909e12528

Answer (score 1):

Laravel version: 9.*

```
// app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    return '/api/unauthenticated'; // You can name whatever route you want
}
```

```
// routes/api.php

Route::get('/unauthenticated', function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 403);
});
```

Hope this helps.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to enforce your api consumer to pass `Accept - application/json` in all the request headers you can add the following method in `App\Exceptions\Handlers.php;` to customize error response

```
   //use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)

    {

        if ($request->is('api/*')) {

            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid token', 'status' => false], 401);

        }



        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

if you are using `username` instead of `email` for credential; insert this method at your `User` model:

```
function findForPassport($username) {
     return $this->where('username', $username)->first();
}
```