# Laravel (v5.7) Passport (v7.0) is redirecting me to the login screen when trying to open auth api route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have read this question: [Laravel Passport Route redirects to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116452/laravel-passport-route-redirects-to-login-page) and it is not working for me. I am sending the request using `Accept: application/json` and `Authorization: Bearer [access-token]`, but i am redirected to the login screen of my app. This is the route i am trying `https://passportdemo.test/api/products` and this is my api route file

```
Route::post('register', 'API\RegisterController@register');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('products', 'API\ProductController');
});
```

I am able to register a new user and login a user without any problems, but when trying to use the products route i am redirected to the login screen. 
I also tried to see what will `dd($request->expectsJson());` return from `namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions@unauthenticated` and it is returning `false` which is strange right? it should return true i think. I am using nginx server so the trick with .htaccess i think its not appellable for me and also i tried to add `protected static $serialize = true;` inside the class `Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies`, but this dosent work for me too.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A noob mistake. It turn out that sending the request using Postman or Insomnia need to be done with the Auth tab and not from the data/form tap (which i was using).

- For Postman just go to Authorization and choose Bearer token and paste the token and fill any data in the Params tab if you need to
- For Insomnia just click on Bearer token and paste your token and then in Multipart if you have some form data paste/write it there

and voila!

after 3 days of researching what is the problem!