# Laravel 5.7 Passport keeps redirecting to login

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-403, laravel-passport, policy

I want to build an API endpoint that gives me a certain object. Some objects are publicly available, some can only be viewed by the owner of that object, until they publish the object.

```
Route::get('jobs/{job}', 'JobController@find')->middleware('auth:api');
```

The JobPolicy should decide what should happen:

```
public function view(User $user, Job $job)
{
    if (!empty($user)) {
        return $job->user_id === $user->id || $job->job_status_id !== 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works, when the user is logged in. When the user is not, this doesn't work anymore.

Like this the `->middleware('auth:api')` prevents the Policy from being reached when not logged in.

---

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116452/laravel-passport-route-redirects-to-login-page) and
[this doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#guest-users) I must be able to change the view-method in the Policy from `view(User $user, Job $job)` to `view(?User $user, Job $job)` in order to have my Policy being reached, even for non-authenticated users.

Problem is that, because of `->middleware('auth:api')` it keeps sending me to `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` with an Unauthenticated error.

Clearly adding the **?** to the JobPolicy isn't the only thing I should be doing.

---

I'm running PHP 7.2, Laravel 5.7 and Laravel Passport 7.2.0.

Comment: Don't add 'auth:api' middleware to your route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Passport now. Adding this on Postman headers solved my problem. Hope this helps to you too

```
Key                      Value
===================================
Accept             application/json
Authorization      Bearer {insert_token_login_here}
```

The **token** can be generated when the user is logged in. Here's my LoginController

```
$user = $request->user();

$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
$token = $tokenResult->token;

  if ($request->remember_me)
   {
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
   }

$token->save();

$message = ['user' => $user,
  'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
  'token_type' => 'Bearer',
  'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
   $tokenResult->token->expires_at
  )->toDateTimeString()
];
```

Comment: Thanks Enrique, but my problem was that a route must've been available for authenticated and non-authenticated users, but based on the found object I needed to check whether they were allowed to view the object or not (public or owner).

Answer (score 0):

I solved thanks to the simple comment Sanjay Chaudhari posted!

Not using `auth:api` did cause a new issue though. That way policies will ook for `Auth::user()` instead of `auth()->guard('api')->user()`. Because I authenticated via a token, `Auth::user()` would be empty.

I made an overall `ApiController` that does the following:

```
class ApiController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Return the logged in user
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return Auth::user() ?? auth()->guard('api')->user();
    }

    public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        return $this->authorizeForUser($this->getUser(), $ability, $arguments);
    }
}
```

And let all of my Api-related controllers extend the ApiController instead of the usual Controller.