# Accessing Passport authorize route using token

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-passport

I am developing a project using Vue, laravel, and passport.

I had access to the API routes using the auth: API middleware so I didn't use laravel session login system, but I want to access the authorize route that passport offer but passport requires web middleware, not API.

I added a passport in a driver for 'web' in guards array in config/auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

using postman I sent a GET request to the route with header containing Authorization token and responded correctly.

but when I opened it in the browser it gave me **Route [login] not defined.** since it doesn't have the Authorization token header

Is there any way it can work through?
In other words, I think the solution of this is sent the token as a header to the passport authorize page which I didn't had access to.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Passport Route redirects to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116452/laravel-passport-route-redirects-to-login-page)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto sorry but no. this didn't help. I've updated my question. The problem is that I can't enter to authorize page as it don't have the token in it's header as an authorization header, but in postman I set it as a header so it's responding and opening the page